# How to write this procedure to get auto-increment alphanumeric id in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tblContact
(   
    SrNo DECIMAL IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    InquiryId VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    SenderName VARCHAR(50), 
    SenderEmail VARCHAR(200),
    SenderSubject VARCHAR(50),
    SenderMessage VARCHAR(MAX),
    IsActive BIT DEFAULT(1),
    IsDelete BIT DEFAULT(0),
    CreatedOn DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    CreatedBy VARCHAR(10),
    UpdatedOn DATETIME,
    UpdatedBy VARCHAR(10)
)
```

Procedure listing is as follows:

```
CREATE PROC Usp_GetNewInquiryId
AS 
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT InquiryId FROM JobPortal.dbo.tblContact)
        DECLARE @PrefixValue VARCHAR(10) = 'INQ'

    DECLARE @InitialValue DECIMAL(10) = 1001

    SELECT InquiryId = @PrefixValue + CAST(ISNULL(MAX(InquiryId), @InitialValue) AS VARCHAR(10)) 
    FROM JobPortal.dbo.tblContact

    ELSE
        /* here I want to eliminate the word 'INQ' from 'INQ1001' towards left side and do increment 1002 from 1001, lastly want to select INQ1002 and so on... */
        SELECT TOP 1 
            InquiryId = @PrefixValue + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUBSTRING(InquiryId, 4, 4)) + 1 
        FROM JobPortal.dbo.tblContact 
        ORDER BY InquiryId DESC
END
```

Desired Output:

- If table is empty then `InquiryId=INQ1001`
- Otherwise `InquiryId=INQ1002`

Comment: please show some sample data and expected output

Comment: check out this  link on how to ask a good question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: First of all: if you have **multiple commands** under your `IF EXISTS` clause, then you **must use** a `BEGIN .... END` block. Right now, **only** the first command (whch I indented) is really getting executed only when the `IF EXISTS` clause is true - the others will be executed **always** .....

Comment: Note that `wanna` and other forms of txtspk, while fine for your social media, may earn downvotes here - generally it is a good idea to write as clearly as you can, to make posts as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the "next available" `InquiryId` for `tblContact`, I would do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_GetNewInquiryId
AS 
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT InquiryId FROM tblContact)
            SELECT 'INQ1001'
        ELSE
            SELECT TOP 1 'INQ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(InquiryId,'INQ','')) + 1) FROM tblContact ORDER BY InquiryId DESC
    END
```

Comment: Thank you sir/ma'm for helping me, please keep in touch.